# What's the granularity of CRC checks in bittorrent transfers like?

Tags: bittorrent, bandwidth, crc

I don't think I've ever successfully used any torrent client in 20 years of trying once in a while.  I'm in a backwater of the data world: I can get about 3000 bytes per second on a dialup connection or 7000 on a 2G cell phone, on a good day.  Most people have no clue what that's like.

So my question is whether I can get a torrent client to checksum, say, at least every megabyte transferred?  There's no point in downloading all week if you had an error on Monday, you're going to waste time and bandwidth and end up with garbage.  PAR files would help but I've only seen those used in a usenet binary context.  Ideally, I'd like to check the CRC at least every 10 minutes, refetch that data if it's wrong, then continue.

I'm looking at a 1.3 gig file I want, which by my calculations will take at least 52 hours.  My bandwidth is also metered for the first (fast) 5 gigs a month, I've already blown this month's quota trying to get this file over HTTP.  Again, PAR files could salvage what I downloaded, but of course most sites don't use them.  I downloaded for 2 days, bad SHA, the whole thing is useless.

Comment: When I had no internet service, I use free wifi at different locations to get files via bittorrent, if took a few visits but got it done.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, but BitTorrent (BT) might still be a good idea for your problem.

BT divides large files into chunks (so-called pieces) and calculates SHA1 hashes for each piece. Pieces can be loaded individually of each other (out of order and also in parallel). After a piece is downloaded completely(!) the SHA1 is checked and if a corruption is found the piece is discarded and downloaded again.

The size of a piece is variable but per-determined by the torrent creator. The default value piece size 256 KiB. Larger torrents usually use larger piece sizes. For example the ubuntu 16.04 ISO (1.3 GiB) uses 512 KiB. The Caine 7.0 ISO (2.9 GiB) uses 1 MiB.

So, if your piece size is not that big, bittorrent will achieve what you desire.

To save bandwidth, maybe you want to disable some BT features like DHT and PeX and rely only on trackers.

You might also want to limit the number of parallel connections and the number of parallel pieces, in order to complete a piece before your connection might break. (I think this can be achieved with the "in order" setting of qBittorrent)

Also many clients (like qBittorrent) can also use HTTP sources in addition to the torrent protocol. Althou I am not sure if they also to the piece checksum thing for HTTP sources.

Comment: +1. May be worth linking to the bittorrent specification, for the more technical users: https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification

Comment: Thank you, that should work.  I'm in OpenBSD right now and the only torrent client I have installed is rtorrent.  The man page doesn't mention CRC at all.  I'm trying to get a Raspbian Jessie image, tried Jessie Lite but there's no X.  Spent a couple days trying to add it.

Comment: Transmission is another BT client with many features and also available for BSD. https://www.transmissionbt.com/

Comment: As the file is larger, the larger the piece size should be.  Otherwise the torrent file itself becomes too large.  So large files tend to have large piece sizes.  Also a downloader cannot change the piece size, this is set by whoever made the .torrent file and is providing the initial seed.  OP should not try to download large file torrents through dialup, but 1.3GB should work fine over your fast (presumably) metered cellular connection.  The total bandwith consumed will probably be like 3.0GB due to exchange with peers and overhead.

Comment: The Raspbian Jessie image uses 1 MiB piece size.

Comment: I see transmission in ports here (OpenBSD 5.7).  I'm trying to use rtorrent after doing some reading.  Stuck bootstrapping my DHT at the moment, not sure I can get port 6881 through my cell phone connection. I ran out of my 5 gigs of fast data last week, now I'm slow for about 3 more weeks.

Comment: Yup:  Name: 2016-03-18-raspbian-jessie.zip
  Hash: 2e72603a377f702ca81020f634ada0ff6731544f
  Created by: Transmission/2.52 (13304)
  Created on: Fri Mar 18 09:29:00 2016
  Piece Count: 1334
  Piece Size: 1.00 MiB
  Total Size: 1.40 GB
  Privacy: Public torrent